# Extract dictionary words from spreadsheet

Tags: excel, dictionary, extract, words

I have spreadsheets of usernames and I need to be able to compile a list of the ones that are proper words found in a dictionary. The closest I've come to solving this is to copy usernames from column A to B. Then run spellcheck on Column A and accept all suggestions while manually deleting the lines spellcheck doesn't have suggestions for. Then run the formula `=IF(A1=B1,B1,"")` in column C to crosscheck column A with B and return the names that haven't changed.

Comment: So what's the problem? Is it not working?

Comment: A lot of usernames pass the spellcheck even though they aren't proper words or even words that have numbers in them.

Comment: Is there a different spell check you can run on them?

Comment: sounds like the problem is *accepting the suggestions* - by offering a suggestion, spellcheck is already saying - "hey, this word doesn't exist (but perhaps you mean this?)" Why not remove the ones that offer suggestion as well. You can also use a formula to figure out if a username as a number value and remove those as well.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

I place the usernames I want to check in column A
Then I found a list of every dictionary word and placed the list in column B.
Then in column C I just use the formula `=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A1,B:B))>0`

This returns a true/false answer to whether any of the names are a proper word.

Comment: You may find [Spellcheck a single word in Excel function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10776191/spellcheck-a-single-word-in-excel-function/36341449#36341449) of interest. I've recently added an updated response largely due to your question. btw, wouldn't `=AND(COUNTIF(B:B, A1))` be more efficient?

Comment: You are correct Jeeped, that does make it function much better. Thank you.