# VBA Excel removing repeatable words from spellcheck

Tags: excel, vba

I have got the document with more than 20 sheets. There are words, which repeat in every sheet. Going through the spell check even when I click the "Ignore all" option, they appear again and again, as I check the document sheet by sheet.

So far I used the code:

```
Sub Spellcheck
For Each sh In Worksheets
Sheets(sh.Name).Cells.CheckSpelling
Next
End Sub
```

I found something, which would be helpful for me here:

[Spellcheck a single word in Excel function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10776191/spellcheck-a-single-word-in-excel-function)

but it doesn't work in my situation
I see the error: **Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment**

[image]

Is there some way to apply the "Remove all" for all sheets at once.

Comment: `Application.CheckSpelling` requires a word to be passed to it... so you might be stuck with `Worksheet.CheckSpelling` or `Range.CheckSpelling` as you are currently using it.

Comment: So is there another, quicker checkspelling then?

Comment: Not as far as I can tell.

Comment: Have you tried adding it to the dictionary? Or when you find a word on one sheet doing a find/replace on the remaining sheets.

Comment: This is a thing. Let me try it tomorrow.

Comment: Basically it works fine, although at the very end I am getting the debug error. Is it something wrong in the code then?